# Is LLVM 3.5 bitcode back compatible to LLVM 3.3 bitcode?

Tags: clang, llvm, emscripten

I'm going to generate LLVM bitcode by Clang 3.5 in one environment (using `-emit-llvm -S -c file.cpp -o file.ll`) and it's executed in another environment by LLVM 3.3 (see `lli` tool). Is it back compatible (can 3.5 bitcode by executed by 3.3 LLVM)?

PS. Actually it's going to be executed by Emscripten (in JS) which is based on LLVM 3.3 trunk (if it makes sense).

Comment: I am able to move between LLVM 3.4 and 3.3, but I don't yet have 3.5 installed to test.

Comment: does it mean "it is back compatible" or "it is compatible in my case for my example"?

Comment: The later, I only verified that LLVM 3.4 bitcode was readable by LLVM 3.3.